# Can a Recursive CTE be used for hierarchical rows with accumulating trickle down sub-joins?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using a recursive CTE for "Groups" in a table using ID and Parent.

The first table "Groups" (Project_Estimate_Group) is hierarchical with ID and parent. The second table "GroupOptions" (Project_Estimate_Group_Option) accommodates a many-to-many relationship between Groups and Options. If you add an Option to any level it trickles down to any child in that branch.

I need to join the parent and recursive children of Groups to GroupOptions and have those joins "trickle" down through each recursion level so that at each level you have a join to the current Options as well as a join to the Options for each parent in the branch.

I need a row for each group without the OptionID and a row for each joined OptionID. Some levels will have no Options.

Can this be done with a recursive CTE?

Table1 "Groups" has

```
Parent   ID
-------- ------
NULL     1
1        2
2        3
NULL     4
4        5
```

Table2 "GroupOptions" has

```
GroupID  OptionID
-------- --------
1        10
1        11
2        12
5        20
```

After joining I need

```
Parent   ID       OptionID
-------- -------- ----------
NULL     1        0
NULL     1        10
NULL     1        11
1        2        0
1        2        10
1        2        11
1        2        12
2        3        0
2        3        10
2        3        11
2        3        12
NULL     4        0
4        5        0
4        5        20
```

The following query will get close but will only return Options for the current Group and its Parent but not its grandparent or above

```
DECLARE @EstimateID int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.Project_Estimate);
WITH egroup (EstimateID, ParentID, GroupID, OptionID) AS
(
SELECT @EstimateID, NULL, peg.ID, 0
FROM dbo.Project_Estimate_Group peg
WHERE peg.Estimate = @EstimateID AND peg.Parent IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT @EstimateID, NULL, peg.ID, pego.OptionID
FROM dbo.Project_Estimate_Group peg
JOIN dbo.Project_Estimate_Group_Option pego on peg.ID = pego.GroupID
WHERE peg.Estimate = @EstimateID AND peg.Parent IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT @EstimateID, peg.Parent, peg.ID, 0
FROM dbo.Project_Estimate_Group peg
  JOIN egroup on peg.Parent = egroup.GroupID
UNION ALL
SELECT @EstimateID, peg.Parent, peg.ID, pego.OptionID
FROM dbo.Project_Estimate_Group peg
  JOIN egroup on peg.Parent = egroup.GroupID
  JOIN dbo.Project_Estimate_Group_Option pego on peg.ID = pego.GroupID
UNION ALL
SELECT @EstimateID, peg.Parent, peg.ID, pego.OptionID
FROM dbo.Project_Estimate_Group peg
  JOIN egroup on peg.Parent = egroup.GroupID
  JOIN dbo.Project_Estimate_Group_Option pego on peg.Parent = pego.GroupID
)

SELECT DISTINCT EstimateID, ParentID, GroupID, OptionID 
FROM egroup
JOIN dbo.Project_Estimate e on egroup.EstimateID = e.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(   
    -- Get all Groups - GroupOptions combinations
    SELECT g.Parent, g.ID, go.OptionID
    FROM Groups g
    INNER JOIN GroupOptions go ON g.ID = go.GroupID  

    UNION ALL

    -- Go down one level passing option value
    SELECT g.Parent, g.ID, c.OptionID
    FROM CTE c
    INNER JOIN Groups g ON c.ID = g.Parent
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE

UNION ALL

-- Union each group row without the OptionID
SELECT Parent, ID, 0
FROM Groups
ORDER BY ID, OptionID
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30aed/1)

Comment: From [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "`;` Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version." Make it a habit to use it.